# Что означает статус сообщения «заблокировано»?

Tags: поддержка, faq, заблокированные-вопросы

Случается, что сообщения получают статус «*заблокировано*».

- Что означает блокировка сообщения?
- Кто может заблокировать сообщение?
- Какие сообщения блокируются?

---

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[What is a “locked” post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/)».</sub>

Answer (score 10):

### Что означает статус *заблокировано*?

Над вопросом или ответом, которые были заблокированы, в дальнейшем не допускается производить следующих действий:

- редактировать;
- голосовать (как «за», так и «против»);
- комментировать, голосовать за комментарии;
- публиковать ответы *<sup>(только для вопросов)</sup>*;
- закрывать и повторно открывать *<sup>(только для вопросов)</sup>*.

Если блокируется вопрос, на (не заблокированные) ответы к нему эти ограничения не распространяются.

Заблокированные сообщения могут впоследствии быть разблокированы модераторами. Также они могут быть [заблокированы временно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106137/better-handling-of-locked-questions-and-answers/106143#106143). Предустановленные временные промежутки блокировки составляют 1 час, 24 часа и 1 неделю.

### Кто может *заблокировать* сообщение?

Заблокировать или разблокировать сообщение могут только модераторы.

### Какие сообщения *блокируются*?

Сообщения следует блокировать только в случае возникновения *по-настоящему неблагоприятной* ситуации, в частности, если внесение обновлений и правок негативно отражается на работе системы.

Примеры сообщений, которые требуют блокировки:

- Вопрос или ответ, голосование по которому или редактирование которого происходит в игровых целях, в попытках взломать систему или иным образом осложнить её работу.
- Вопрос, который многократно открывается и закрывается без консенсуса со стороны сообщества о его открытии или закрытии.
- Вопрос, который по какой бы то ни было причине порождает волну грубых или оскорбительных сообщений, спама или нерелевантных ответов.
- Вопрос, к которому его автор относится по-хулигански: например, кардинально меняет его смысл, что делает ответы на него нерелевантными, удаляет вопрос или делает его формулировку размытой и неточной.

Еще один тип сообщений, которые должны быть заблокированы – вопросы, созданные слиянием. Когда модератор производит слияние двух точно повторяющих друг друга вопросов, все ответы переносятся в один вопрос, а другой вопрос становится «заглушкой» без ответов и поэтому блокируется.

### Как быть, если я не согласен с *блокировкой* сообщения?

Если у вас есть *уважительная* причина для разблокировки сообщения, вам следует привлечь внимание модератора сигналом тревоги – используя ссылку «тревога» под сообщением. В качестве причины тревоги укажите «другое» и подробно опишите свои соображения в появившимся окне.

Модератор обратит внимание на вашу тревогу и, в случае согласия с аргументами, разблокирует сообщение.

Эта процедура не применима к сообщениям, заблокированным по причине исторической важности: в этом случае сигнал тревоги использовать невозможно.