# Что такое «защищённый» вопрос?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Некоторые вопросы имеют статус *защищённый*.

- Если вопрос защищён, что это значит?
- Кто может защищать вопросы?
- Кто может отвечать на защищённые вопросы?
- В каких случаях следует защищать вопросы, а в каких — отменять защиту?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса «[What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/)».</sub>

Answer (score 6):

### Если вопрос защищён, что это значит?

[Защита](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/) вопроса не позволяет [новым участникам](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) отвечать на него.  В отличие от [заблокированных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3293/6) вопросов, у участников сохраняется возможность редактировать защищённые вопросы, комментировать их и голосовать по ним, в том числе голосовать за закрытие защищённых вопросов.

### Почему некоторым вопросам необходима защита?

Вопрос следует защитить, если предполагается, что он вызовет волну спама или привлечёт множество участников (зачастую новых), которые могут ошибочно принять наш сайт за обычный форум и начать публиковать ответы, создающие информационный шум (например, «Спасибо!», «Мне помогло» или «У меня такая же проблема»).

### Кто может защищать вопросы или отменять их защиту?

- [Модераторы, чьи имена отмечены символом ромба](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/what-are-diamond-moderators).
- Пользователи, обладающие как минимум 15 000 баллов репутации, могут защищать вопросы или отменять защиту спустя сутки после публикации вопроса.
- Система (силами [Духа сообщества](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)) [автоматически устанавливает защиту](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers/89971#89971), если:

  1. среди ответов, полученных на вопрос, три ответа от участников с низкой репутацией были удалены или...
  2. [за последние 24 часа на вопрос было получено 5 ответов от участников с низкой репутацией](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226619/auto-protect-questions-that-get-more-than-n-answers-from-new-users-in-a-24-hour).

### Кто может отвечать на защищённые вопросы?

На защищённый вопрос могут отвечать участники с уровнем репутации не менее 10 баллов. При этом **не учитываются +100 баллов репутации, полученные в качестве бонуса за подключение учётных записей других сайтов**. Следовательно, отвечать на защищённый вопрос смогут только участники, набравшие не менее 10 баллов репутации на конкретном сайте, содержащем этот вопрос.

### В каких случаях следует защищать вопросы, а в каких — отменять защиту?

- Защищайте вопросы, если на них поступает множество неуместных или некачественных ответов (спам и т. д.) от новых пользователей.
- Не следует защищать вопросы только потому, что они содержат ссылки на популярные новостные сайты.
- Следует отменить защиту, если в настоящее время вопрос привлекает внимание участников, а предыдущие ответы на него соответствовали требованиям.

См. также: [Изменения и рекомендации по использованию статуса «Защищённый вопрос»](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/)

Comment: Тут наверно ошибка в тексте: Следует отменить защиту, если в настоящее время вопрос привлекает внимание участников, а предыдущие ответы на него НЕ соответствовали требованиям.