# Как определяется "повышенная активность" у вопросов?

Tags: поддержка, защищённые-вопросы

Сегодня попал на такое ([сам вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1218243/ruby-on-rails-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-permission-denied-rb-file-s-rename))

[image: вопрос с повышенной активностью]

Как видно, у вопроса 56 просмотров за 11 месяцев, что повышенной активностью никак не назвать. Откуда у него тогда такой статус?

*PS. Ссылка ведет на страницу о защищенных вопросах и ситуацию с повышенной активностью никак не проясняет.*

Comment: «Вопрос защищён участником insolor» — вот так видимо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое «защищённый» вопрос?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5636/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%89%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81)

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос был защищён участником (видно в [истории изменений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1218243/revisions)):

[image]

Comment: это вам на вопросе такая плашка показывается? Или откуда этот скриншот?

Comment: @Эникейщик в истории изменений вопроса

Comment: тогда непонятно, почему на плашке написано "с повышеной активностью" вместо "вопрос защищен".